Ubuntu 24.10, sudo: gedit: command not found
I am attempting to follow instructions for editing /etc/fstab at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving.
I get the following error message:
steven@steven-Vostro-7620:~$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
steven@steven-Vostro-7620:~$ cmp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
steven@steven-Vostro-7620:~$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab 
sudo: gedit: command not found

I searched Ask Ubuntu but the only suggestions were for other programs, not gedit.

oh even better, thanks also.

The default text editor has changed
Gedit, the default text editor, was replaced by a brand new editor, Gnome Text Editor in Ubuntu 22.10 and above.
Use the command:
sudo gnome-text-editor /etc/fstab 

instead. Alternately you may use a text based (non GUI) editor like nano:
sudo nano /etc/fstab

Sometimes nano is more convenient.
Hope this helps

Try the following command: sudo apt install gedit
It will install the gedit text editor.
after that, you will be able to use gedit to modify the fstab file.
have a nice day

try installing it,
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gedit
